Pin the before content when doing horizontal scroll
I am using GSAP for horizontal scrolling. Here it is working but I need to stick the above inro also untill horizontal scroll end. Currently it scrolls up and horizontal scrolling start.
<div class="container">
    <div class="process__intro__wrap" >
        <div class="process__intro">
            <div class="process__intro__title">
                <% if $ShowTitle %>
                    <h2>{$Title}</h2>
                <% end_if %>
            </div>
            <div class="process__intro__desc">
                $ElementProcessDescription
            </div>
        </div>
        <% if $ElementProcessLink %>
        <div class="process__intro__cta">
            <a href="$ElementProcessLink.LinkURL" class="btn">
                {$ElementProcessLink.Title}
                <% include SVG/arrow %>
            </a>
        </div>
        <% end_if %>
    </div>
    <div class="process__grid__wrap">
        <div class="mobile-hide" >
            <div class="process__grid horiz-gallery-wrapper"  > 
                <div class="process__items horiz-gallery-strip">
                        <% loop $getPathwayElements %>
                            <div class="process__item sticky-process-item ">
                                <div class="process__item__title">
                                    <div class="process__item__num">
                                        <h4>$Counter</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="process__item__topic">
                                        <h4>$Title</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="process__item__desc">
                                    $Description.Raw
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <% end_loop %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="process__grid desktop-hide" data-fadein> 
        <div class="process__items js-clients-carousel">
                <% loop $getPathwayElements %>
                    <div class="process__item">
                        <div class="process__item__title">
                            <div class="process__item__num">
                                <h4>$Counter</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="process__item__topic">
                                <h4>$Title</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="process__item__desc">
                            $Description.Raw
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% end_loop %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This is the js code which is using GSAP scrolling should be happen if there are more than 2 elements. currently block intro scrolls up then starts horizontal scrolling. It looks odd in big screens.
``
import gsap from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

export default () => {
  const buildProcess = document.querySelectorAll(".process");
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  const processBlocks = gsap.utils.toArray('.process');

  processBlocks.forEach((processBlock) => {
    const horizontalSections = gsap.utils.toArray(processBlock.querySelectorAll('.horiz-gallery wrapper'));
    const processElements = processBlock.querySelectorAll('.sticky-process-item');

    if (processElements.length > 2) {
      horizontalSections.forEach((sec) => {
        const pinWrap = sec.querySelector(".horiz-gallery-strip");

        if (!pinWrap) {
          console.warn('No pinWrap found for', sec);
          return;
        }

        let pinWrapWidth;
        let horizontalScrollLength;

        function refresh() {
          pinWrapWidth = pinWrap.scrollWidth + 320; // Adjust width as needed
          horizontalScrollLength = pinWrapWidth - window.innerWidth;
          
        }

        refresh();

        gsap.to(pinWrap, {
          scrollTrigger: {
            scrub: 1,
            trigger: processBlock.querySelector('.process__grid__wrap'), // Use the grid wrap as the trigger
            pin: true,
            start: "center center", // Adjust to control when the horizontal scroll should start
            end: () => `+=${pinWrapWidth}`,
            invalidateOnRefresh: true,
            onEnter: () => console.log(`Entering ${sec}`),
            onLeave: () => console.log(`Leaving ${sec}`)
          },
          x: () => -horizontalScrollLength,
          ease: "none"
        });

        ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refreshInit", refresh);
      });
    }
  });
};`

`
I tried to change start atribute but it was not success.

Welcome to SO! It seems there are no .process elements in your HTML or at least you haven't included them in your question. Therefor gsap.utils.toArray returns a empty Array. Please add all relevant code parts as a MRE
